# Retrieve record count of subreport in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I retrieve the record count of a subreport from within the main report?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98025/cores-em-subreport

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a dupe, but I'll answer anyway. :)

You can create a formula field on the subreport which contains a shared variable. In the formula you'll set the shared variable to the value of the rowcount field in the subreport.

Then in your main report you will need to create a formula with a shared variable that has the same name as the subreport and then return the value of the shared variable.

Here are some links that may help.
http://www.datamanagementgroup.com/Resources/TrainersTalk/trainerstalk_howto_share_subreport_data_with_main_report.asp
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=19034

Answer (score 0):

1. Put this formula in your subreport. You can suppress it from display if you like.

   whileprintingrecords;
       Shared numbervar SubRecordCount:=(however you want to count the records in the report);
2. Put this in your main report.  Again, this can also be suppressed.

   whileprintingrecords;
   shared numbervar SubRecordCount;
   SubRecordCount
3. Use the formula name for #2 for whatever calculations you need.
   IMPORTANT: Due to the fundamental logic of Crystal, you can only use this field if it is BELOW it's subreport.
   Also, as for counting the records in the subreport, I recommend a running total at the bottom of it.

Answer (score -1):

here you can retrive sub report count from code side

===========================

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument RepDoc = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

RepDoc.Load(ReportName);

int IntRepCount = RepDoc.Subreports.Count;
```

===========================

pass this count to your report

Comment: This returns the number of subreports used in the main report, not the number of records in the subreport